# Is there a better way to assign the biggest of two values to a property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I've always done this to assign the biggest of two values to something:

```
var targetHeight = (minHeight < $(window).height()) ? $(window).height() : minHeight;
```

Is there something tidier / shorter / trickier I can do with different operators?

Would be nice to have something along the lines of:

```
// Use minHeight if it's greater than the window height.
var targetHeight = minHeight > $(window).height();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
var targetHeight = Math.max(minHeight, $(window).height());
```

Comment: You beat me to it buy a few seconds :[

Comment: I didn't think there was a better way. Good one!